# How to sync improvements from a skeleton of a github project with mine that was manually downloaded and modified?

Tags: git, github, gitlab-ci

I manually downloaded a skeleton of a project from github months ago and made changes. I realized that this project skeleton has some improvements that I want to use in my project that is downloaded on my machine. What git commands should I use to sync the skeleton improvements with my local?
The project I downloaded is this: https://github.com/odan/slim4-skeleton

Comment: either `pull` or `fetch` with the skeleton's repo to get what it knows into your local repo.  It sounds like that should be set as your upstream, so you can regularly do that.

Comment: Can you tell, please, what is the command?

Comment: [`git pull` -- Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)